# React Syncfusion saved layout cannot be set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, syncfusion, react-tsx

I am working in React typescript and more specifically making a pivot table report, I am using syncfusion components for this app. Everything works as expected but their documentation does not explain specifically how to save a report to a json file. I want to save the report settings (data layout) in a variable that later will be converted to a JSON to be stored in a server, the save function works I console log it and it returns the correct settings, then I try to load the saved settings it does not work, I am using their setProperties function but it does not work. Also, it seems that whenever I load a report it runs the save function I don't know why maybe because a rerender runs or something I don't know.

This is my component code. There is nothing else that could cause the problem the data that I am passing works as expected just the layout doesn't work that's the problem. The load button is a custom button because I do not want to use their load, you can read the documentation here: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/pivotview/tool-bar?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=ts

```
import { PivotViewComponent, IDataOptions, IDataSet, FieldList, CalculatedField, Toolbar, PDFExport, ExcelExport, ConditionalFormatting, SaveReportArgs, FetchReportArgs, LoadReportArgs, RemoveReportArgs, RenameReportArgs, ToolbarArgs, NumberFormatting, Inject, PivotView } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-pivotview';
import '@syncfusion/ej2-base/styles/material-dark.css';
import '@syncfusion/ej2-buttons/styles/material-dark.css';
import '@syncfusion/ej2-calendars/styles/material-dark.css';
import '@syncfusion/ej2-dropdowns/styles/material-dark.css';
import '@syncfusion/ej2-inputs/styles/material-dark.css';
import '@syncfusion/ej2-navigations/styles/material-dark.css';
import '@syncfusion/ej2-popups/styles/material-dark.css';
import '@syncfusion/ej2-react-grids/styles/material-dark.css';
import '@syncfusion/ej2-react-grids/styles/material-dark.css';
import '@syncfusion/ej2-react-pivotview/styles/material-dark.css';
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

interface iPivotReportProps {
    dataRows: {}[]; //Data sent from server
    dataLayout?: {}; //Also sent from server
    enableLayoutChange?: boolean;
    enableLayoutSave?: boolean;
    enableLayoutLoad?: boolean;
    enableAgregateFunction?: boolean;
    enableDataExport?: boolean;
    enablePdfExport?: boolean;
    reportTitle?: boolean;
}

export default function PivotReport({dataRows, dataLayout, enableLayoutChange=false, enableLayoutSave=false, enableLayoutLoad=false,
    enableAgregateFunction=false, enableDataExport=false, enablePdfExport=false, reportTitle}: iPivotReportProps) {
    
    const [report, setReport] = useState<any>(null);
    const pivotObj = useRef<PivotViewComponent>(null);

    function saveReport() {
        const dataSourceSettings = pivotObj.current?.dataSourceSettings;
        console.log(dataSourceSettings);
        setReport(dataSourceSettings)
    }
    function loadReport() {
        if(pivotObj)
        {
            console.log(report.properties)
            pivotObj.current?.setProperties({
                dataSource: {}
            })
            pivotObj.current?.refresh();
        }
    }


    let toolbarOptions: any = ['Grid', 'Chart', 'SubTotal', 'GrandTotal'];;
    if(enableLayoutChange) toolbarOptions.push('FieldList', 'Formatting');
    if(enableLayoutSave) { toolbarOptions.push('Save'); }
    if(enableLayoutLoad) { toolbarOptions.push('Load'); }
    if(enableDataExport || enablePdfExport) toolbarOptions.push('Export');
    
    return (
        <div className="PivotTable">
            <PivotViewComponent dataSourceSettings={{dataSource: dataRows}} ref={pivotObj} width={'100%'} height={'1000px'} showToolbar={true} showFieldList={enableLayoutChange} allowExcelExport={enableDataExport} allowNumberFormatting={enableLayoutChange} allowConditionalFormatting={enableLayoutChange} allowPdfExport={enablePdfExport} allowCalculatedField={enableAgregateFunction} displayOption={{ view: "Both" }} toolbar={toolbarOptions} saveReport={saveReport} >
                <Inject services={[FieldList, CalculatedField, Toolbar, ExcelExport, PDFExport, ConditionalFormatting, NumberFormatting]} />
            </PivotViewComponent>
            <button onClick={loadReport}>Load</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have tried to set the properties with 100 different values but nothing works. I tried to use their Interface called IDataOptions also does not work even brings up an error and copying their code gives an error don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the loaded report settings is not assigned to the component, instead you have emptied the data source while loading the report. Thus, I suggest you assign the loaded report settings to the pivot table component. Please refer the below code example to assign the report settings to the component while loading the report based on your needs.

Code Example:

```
loadReport(args) {

 // Here, we have called our API service by passing the report information to load the report. Instead of this you can call your service here.

  fetch('https://localhost:44313/Pivot/LoadReport', {

    method: 'POST',

    headers: {

      'Accept': 'application/json',

      'Content-Type': 'application/json',

    },

    body: JSON.stringify({ reportName: args.reportName })

  }).then(res => res.json())

    .then(response => {

      if (response) {

        var report = JSON.parse(response);

                       // Assign the loaded report data settings to the component here.

                        pivotObj.dataSourceSettings = report.dataSourceSettings;



                                                (OR)

                      // If you want to load the dataSourceSettings along with grid settings, you can use setProperties.

                     pivotObj.setProperties({

               dataSourceSettings: report.dataSourceSettings,

               gridSettings: report.gridSettings

      })

                                             (OR)

                    // To load all of the settings contained in the loaded report (dataSourceSettings, gridSettings, chartSettings, and displayOption), use loadPersistData().

                       pivotObj.loadPersistData(args.report);

      }

    });

},
```

Also noticed that you save and load reports on a server. If so, you can refer to the documentation and GitHub samples below for details on how to save and load the report in a SQL database.

Document: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/pivotview/tool-bar#save-and-load-reports-to-a-sql-database

Github sample: GitHub - SyncfusionExamples/Save-and-load-report-from-SQL-database-to-pivot-table: Save and load report from SQL Server Database to a Pivot Table